# Why isn't eclipse displaying any information

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java. I need to know, let's say, I am to use the `Random` class. When I hover onto the `Random` class, it doesn't display me any information like the "the random class is used to creating random integer", or is this like a buy in Eclipse[image: As you can see the on the right side it show blank is this what it meant to show or the meaning of the random class]

Is this how it meant to be? Please help, I am new to programming.

Comment: Are you asking why it doesn't display the Javadocs?

Comment: yes like you know on the right side isn't their meant to be some kind of information about the random class do you think i need to re-install eclipse.

Comment: Probably, in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ you have a JRE instead of JDK configured. It might be also a bug of one of the plug-ins you obviously installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're speaking about the popup  tooltip that displays information about an item; Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Hovers.

If you're speaking about the javadoc of a class; Go to Window > show view > javadoc
in javadoc view, right click and open attached javadoc to display the javadoc.

Comment: cheer i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to display detailed information of the methods, class, declaration... when you hover over in Eclipse is to press CTRL while you hover.